# Selecting the first values from a MultiIndexed dataframe with two levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am relatively new to python, so please excuse any confusion which may arrise due to my bad terminology.

Anyways, I am currently stuck with trying to obtain the first value for each index of level 2 of a multiindexed dataframe. The df has 2 indexes, level 1 being 'user' and level 2 being 'trial'. Both 'user' and 'trial' are integer values, while 't' are continuous float values.

Basically I want to extract the first 't' value of the following dataframe for each trial, for each user: df=[dataframe in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRMMQ.png).

I have used `df['user'].unique()` and `df['trial'].unique()` (before doing `df.set_index(['user','trial'])`)and discovered that there are 1040 unique users and 97 unique trials. The main problem is that not each user has the same unique trial numbers (i.e. user 1 has a trial number 5, while user 2 does nit, and so on).

Is there anyway to obtain these values and later compile them in a similar dataframe, df2, which is also indexed by 'user' and 'trial'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [pd.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user', 'trial'], keep='first')
df = df.set_index(['user', 'trial'])
```

(replace `<column>`by the name of the column containing the values you want to sort)

Comment: Thanks, worked great! I can't believe I didn't think of using `pd.drop_duplicates`. One small thing though, `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user', 'trial', 't'], keep='first')` shouldn't include 't' as 't' does not have any duplicates. Either way, thank you once again!

Comment: You're right, my mistake ;). Editing my answer right now.